# Java 8 double for loop to stream filter map

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, java-stream

My code as it is:

```
List<TestDto> dto = selectList();
List<TestDto2> dto2 = selectList2();
Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

for( TestDto d : dto )
{
  for( TestDto2 d2 : dto2 )
  {
    if( (d1.getHeight() == d2.getHeight()) && (d1.getAge() == d2.getAge()) ) 
    {
      result.put( d2.getName() + "_H", d1.getHeight() );
      result.put( d2.getName() + "_A", d1.getAge() );
    }
  }
}
```

To be:

```
    ?
/*
    example) dto.stream().filter(dto2.stream(d2... -> d1.getHeight = d2.getHeight && d1.getAge == d2.getAge).map....result.put()...
*/
```

I want Java 8 Stream code.

Who can help me?

Using Java 8 streams I want to Stream from for loop,
get all map,  list of all the filtered objects.

Comment: Are `TestDto` and `TestDto2` actually two different classes?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile unless `getHeight` is a public boolean field.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, it's better to be done in the way you have already done it. However, if you still want to use `Stream` API, you can do it in the following way:

```
dto.stream().forEach(d1 -> dto2.stream().forEach(d2 -> {
    if (d1.getHeight() == d2.getHeight() && d1.getAge() == d2.getAge()) {
        result.put(d2.getName() + "_H", d1.getHeight());
        result.put(d2.getName() + "_A", d1.getAge());
    }
}));
```

In fact, you do not need to use `dto.stream()`. You can simply use [`ArrayList#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
dto.forEach(d1 -> dto2.forEach(d2 -> {
    if (d1.getHeight() == d2.getHeight() && d1.getAge() == d2.getAge()) {
        result.put(d2.getName() + "_H", d1.getHeight());
        result.put(d2.getName() + "_A", d1.getAge());
    }
}));
```

Comment: You don't need to call `stream()` in that case if you call `forEach()` then directly.

Answer (score 2):

```
dto2.stream().filter(testDto2 -> dto.stream().
                anyMatch(testDto ->
                        testDto2.getAge() == testDto.getAge() && testDto2.getHeight() == testDto.getHeight()))
                .forEach(testDto2 ->
                        {
                            result.put(testDto2.getName() + "_H", testDto2.getHeight());
                            result.put(testDto2.getName() + "_A", testDto2.getAge());

                        }
                );
```

Comment: It is not a good way to go since the Stream API produces a side-effect.

Answer (score 1):

```java
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;

Map<String, Object> result =
        dto.stream()
           .flatMap(d1 -> dto2.stream().map(d2 -> Pair.of(d1, d2)))
           .filter(pair -> pair.getLeft().getHeight() == pair.getRight().getHeight())
           .filter(pair -> pair.getLeft().getAge() == pair.getRight().getAge())
           .flatMap(pair -> Stream.of(
                   Pair.of(pair.getRight().getName() + "_H", pair.getLeft().getHeight()),
                   Pair.of(pair.getRight().getName() + "_A", pair.getLeft().getAge())))
           .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getLeft, Pair::getRight));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use your existing approach with the following changes.

```
List<TestDto> dto = selectList();
List<TestDto2> dto2 = selectList2();
Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

outer:
for (TestDto2 d2 : dto2) {
    for (TestDto d1 : dto) {
        if ((d1.getHeight() == d2.getHeight())
                && (d1.getAge() == d2.getAge())) {
            result.put(d2.getName() + "_H", d1.getHeight());
            result.put(d2.getName() + "_A", d1.getAge());
            continue outer;
        }
    }
}
```

- Reverse the order of the loops so the outer one has the name attribute
- Once a match is found and the entries entered in the map, continue the outer loop.

If you were printing this instead of putting in a map, the above would avoid duplicates showing up.  Since maps ignore duplicate keys, it still ensures you don't do unnecessary comparisons once a match is made.

However, you will still have a problem if you have two people with the same name but different age and/or height.  The most recent one will replace the existing one. One way to deal with that is to also append a number to the names and then increment the number.  This would ensure you could have multiples of the same name.